# Woocommerce mini-cart click issue redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My problem is with the mini-cart button.

When you click the mini-cart button it should **redirect** to the **Cart Page** and it's not working , same problem on mobile .

Here is the cart button code ,I have tried to fix it but I am no expert.
This is my test [website.](http://dev.ilikeprintful.com/new-ilikeprintful/shop/)

```
<button href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="ql_cart-btn">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( WC()->cart->get_cart_total() ); ?>
    <span class="count">(<?php echo esc_html( WC()->cart->cart_contents_count );?>)</span>
    <i class="ql-bag"></i>
    <i class="ql-chevron-down"></i>
</button>
```

Mobile main issue

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you have issue cart not updated

Comment: @VasimVanzara what do you mean cart not update ? The main problem is on mobile since you cant go to the cart page by pressing the mini-cart even if you have products in it .Can it be fixed ? Thank You

Comment: @Bogdan Laza I have checked this issue when I clicked on a mini-cart button but it does not redirect. Would you please add a screenshot?

Comment: @purvik7373 Added the screenshot up, please check . Thank You .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue :**

Button never use a href so you need to make it working with javascript.

```
<button href="http://dev.ilikeprintful.com/new-ilikeprintful/cart/" class="ql_cart-btn">
```

or use

```
<a href="http://dev.ilikeprintful.com/new-ilikeprintful/cart/" class="ql_cart-btn">
<!-- Your code -->
</a>
```

**Your existing code**

```
<div class="ql_cart_wrap">
    <a href="http://dev.ilikeprintful.com/new-ilikeprintful/cart/" class="ql_cart-btn">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>49.90</span>
        <span class="count">(2)</span>
        <i class="ql-bag"></i><i class="ql-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="ql_woo_cart">
    </div><!-- /ql_woo_cart --> 
</div>
```

**How can I Redirect keep the code same**

You can  add onclick event to navigate through button.

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'http://dev.ilikeprintful.com/new-ilikeprintful/cart/';"  >
 //Your Code
</button>
```

Comment: you mean that the button is not using the link ? and how can i do it with javascript  ?

Comment: yes,did you know html?button doesn't have property like href

Comment: i see,I changed it to <a> tag but for some reason it wont change into the page .

Comment: i added the button inside <a></a> and it works .I hope its not a problem .Thanks for all :) .